# $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-1}(e^x-1)^{-1}dx $

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I need to show that I= $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-1}(e^x-1)^{-1}dx = \Gamma(a) \times \Sigma n^{-a}$ where $a > 1$

I have no clue how to approach !

I am using $\Gamma(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt$

Comment: What definition of $\Gamma(a)$ are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^\infty x^{a-1}(1 - e^{-x})^{-1}e^{-x}\, dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty x^{a-1}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (e^{-x})^n\, dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty x^{a-1}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty e^{-nx}\, dx\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \int_0^\infty x^{a-1} e^{-nx}\, dx\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{a}} \int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-x}\, dx\\
&= \Gamma(a)\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-a}.
\end{align}

The interchange of sum and integral is justified by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: How do you justify going from $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}x^{a-1}e^{-nx}dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a}\int_0^{\infty}x^{a-1}e^{-x}dx$, where does the $1/n^a$ come from? Thanks!

Comment: @user110320 use $u$-substitution $u = nx$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $$\frac{1}{e^x-1} = \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-kx}$$